# Access html elements in the lwc's javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-community, login

I am trying to create lwc component for community login.
I have a plain html with input text to accept username and password. I need to access values entered in text-boxes , in the javascript to perform validations.
Below is the html code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-semibold" for="userName">Username:</label>
        <div class="input-affix">
            <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-user"></i>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-semibold" for="password">Password:</label>
        <a class="float-right font-size-13 text-muted" href="">Forget Password?</a>
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-lock"></i>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `this.template.querySelectorAll('.form-control')` to get username and password values in the JS. But it was not helpful. I get values as - `SecureNodeList: [object NodeList]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }`
when I log it in the cosole.
How can I access these values in the JS?

Comment: What do you mean "not helpful"?

Comment: I updated the original question. This- this.template.querySelectorAll('.form-control') logs as - SecureNodeList: [object NodeList]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } in the console.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using? If you are trying to log the actual input component itself, you will get nothing (as above). If you extract the value, as in my example, it's accessible.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and simplified it down to just the two inputs:

```
<lightning-card title="Login">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <lightning-button label="Test" icon-name="utility:save" onclick={getValues}></lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
```

My very basic Javacript handler looks like this:

```
getValues(event) {
  const inputs = this.template.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
  inputs.forEach( input => {
    console.log(input.value);
  });
}
```

This logs out whatever is in the inputs.

Note that `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList - which is not strictly an Array - but in `ES6` it's iterable.

If you are having problems with the nodelist, you can destructure into an array like so:

```
const arrayofinputs = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('.form-control')];
```

Comment: It seems input doesn't have a value attribute. This is what it logs for input -SecureNodeList: [object NodeList]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

Comment: @ManishAnand That's just the nature of how the Locker Service's implementation of Proxy works. Did you try to actually get the values out?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, I tried. input.value doesn't log anything.

Comment: My example is using the latest api, which means Locker Service is running. Have you actually made a demo component with the exact code I used above? Because it works.